# python win32com excel set interval between labels

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am trying to use the win32com module to change some chart's interval between labels.

For example this is the default:

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 (every 1 digit)

And I want to change it into:

0        5          10 (every 5 digits)

the chart's type is set to be combo, with stacked area and lines.

I want to change the intervals between the labels, it's easy to do in excel, 
just go to Format Axis -- Labels -- specify interval units.

But I haven't found a way to do this with win32com in python.

Appreciate any help.

Sorry I can't post any pictures

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out, it seems like the property that needs to change is TckLabelSpacing.

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
ws = excel.ActiveSheet
print ws.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Axes(1).TickLabelSpacing
```